# Integrating iOS native code in IBM Worklight

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a native Barcode Scanner app for iOS using single view controller that consists of:

1. app delegate files i.e `.h` and `.m`
2. view controller files i.e `.h` and `.m` with `xib`

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in [this pdf](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/work%20light/docs/v620/07_03_iOS_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf).

I have observed that there are some Xcode delegate files and some view controllers by default in native/classes folder that is in iOS environment.
But I am not able to understand where to add the above created files (of my native app) to  Worklight environment created for iPhone.

Comment: if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. You edit config.xml with your plug-in declaration
2. You implement JavaScript code to call it up as mentioned in the training module
3. You build your Worklight application and open the generated Xcode project in Xcode
   Right-click the apps\your_app\iphone folder > Run As > Xcode project
4. You add your .m and .h files in Xcode and place them in the Classes folder

You cannot do step 4 in Eclipse; Worklight can't reference your native implementation files in the .pbxproj, that is why you must do it in Xcode.

What you Could do, AFTER step 4, is:

1. Copy the native\config.xml file to nativeResources
2. Copy the native\Classes folder to nativeResources\Classes (also place there your implementation files)
3. Copy the native\xcodeproj folder (that is how Eclipse sees that .xcodeproj file) to native\nativeResources

Now the next time you edit your .m and .h files and/or re-build and re-open your project, the files will remain referenced.